# how to close an established network connection in linux and osx

Tags: linux, macos, networking

I used to do this in the Windows world with tool called TCPView: just select a  established connection (ESTABLISHED), then select "Close Connection". I can't find a way to this on Mac OSX or Linux (I need both). The only way I know of is to kill the process that has the port open.

My main use case is to simulate interruptions in connectivity to test failover, like unplugging a cable or losing a router or middleware situations.

Comment: Killing the process is not good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach to your process using gdb and `close()` the file descriptor corresponding to the connection. You can find out the file descriptor number using `lsof -a -i4 -p $PID`.

Comment: works! too bad gdb pauses the program, but I'll look more into that

Answer (score 2):

- `tcpkill -i eth0 { expression }`
  (basic command/options)
- `tcpkill -i eth0 port 21`
  (Kill all outgoing ftp (port 21) connection)
- `tcpkill host 192.168.1.2`
  or
  `tcpkill host hostname.domainname.com`
  (Kill all all packets arriving at or departing from host 192.168.1.2)
- `tcpkill ip host 192.168.1.2 and not 192.168.1.111`
  (To kill all IP packets between 192.168.1.2 and any host except 192.168.1.111)